# Recompiles iis6 32-bit asp.net 3.5 running on 64-bit Windows Server 2003

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I'm running a 32-bit asp.net app on iis6 on windows server 2003 (64-bit) and am encountering the following problems:

1. App takes 15-20 seconds to spin up.
2. App works quickly for a bit.
3. Something happens - maybe a recompile? The app takes 15-20 seconds to spin up again.

Nothing odd in Event Viewer or IIS logs- page eventually gets served up with a 200. Security log shows NETWORK SERVICE calling IUSR "success."

Also running filezilla server and Symantec Endpoint Protection.

Any ideas how to further trace this or what to check in my configuration?

The application isn't restarting- it seems to start fine and then take requests from one of my browsers. When I switch to another browser and start trying to access the site, it hangs for a couple of minutes.

I logged application-start in global.asax.cs and it starts fine - and quickly.

Comment: this might be because application restarts - try logging Application_Start event from global.asax to verify if this the case.

Comment: Logging - it doesn't run during the hangs but does run when I recycle the app pool and hit it the first time. It runs pretty quickly on the first time. Now it's IE that seems to be going slow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not the issue - it's been set properly to 32-bit mode. Unsolved

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the application pool allows 32 bit application? In advanced box of application pool there are a setting to allow this.

Check this screendump, with the standard setting for 64 bit machine (false) enabled.
http://tinyurl.com/3jcr9mw

Comment: I can't find a way to get to that screen within 64-bit Windows 2003 from the app pool box. I don't see "advanced"

Comment: Are there any settings that would cause requests to serialize??

Comment: @Caveatrob, use of session (read/write mode) can make requests to serialize but this is rare scenario in Web App UI because generally there are no concurrent requests per session (scenario is possible in web services where you enabled session support for services).

Comment: I lately tested from my PC but the other day I was having my boss in another state do hers as well. Is there some other diagnostics or logging I can do to work this out?

Comment: @Caveatrob Ah 2003, whew. I found this: To enable IIS 6.0 to run 32-bit applications on 64-bit Windows 1. Open a command prompt and navigate to the %systemdrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts directory. 2. Type the following command: cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 “true” 3. Press ENTER. This is cut n paste from MS page http://tinyurl.com/276qb8

Comment: I have to say, your symptoms are not really refer to expected symptoms for 32/64 bit mixing. Though, server have to run in same mode as the binaries (also you have to use same bit-binaries in same app.